# PMTA: how to debug the pmtahttp service? (pmta http doesn't start)

Tags: http, nginx, powermta, pmta

Something makes me crazy, I use Power MTA to send emails and I would like to access it via http and the pmtahttp service can't start:

**What I tried :**

- my PMTA conf file contain:

  ```
  http-access myip admin
  http-mgmt-port 8080
  ```

**Problem:**

The service pmtahttp doesn't want to start (FAILED).

**What I tried :**

- to reboot the server : KO
- to change the port : KO
- to check the log: nothing new is logged since the service has "crashed" : KO

For the PMTA service we can debug with:

```
   /pmtad -debug
```

or

```
   /usr/sbin/pmtad –debug
```

Any idea how to debug the service pmtahttp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 chown pmta:pmta /usr/sbin/pmtahttpd
 chmod 755 /usr/sbin/pmtahttpd
```

and to debug the PMTA Http service :

```
  pmtahttpd -debug
```

This solved the problem, if it can help some people..